# Word wrap in JasperReport with html tag

Tags: html, jasper-reports

I´m trying to develop a report with some text, but I got one problem...In text field I wrote i text and use `<br> </br>` tag.

If i wrote one text with this code.

`<br>I want to make</br> <br>word wrap</br>`

The output text will be displayed like this

I want to make (2 word wrap lines) word wrap

So i want to see like this

I want to make (1 word wrap line) word wrap

My JasperStudio version is 5.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean that you are getting two line breaks? Remove the `</br>` tags. You don't need to end a line break tag. Just place `<br>` where you want the line break.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp

Comment: It works, thanks a lot, i put in ´Markup´ the property ´Html´ and the line broke...